# Function in JavaScript has preceding property? Why?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a JS file that i'm working in from a previous employee and there code has functions that look like this:

```
funcName: function funcName() {
     //Some stuff here
    }
```

I've never seen a function start with "funcName:" before.

I removed it and the code still works.

Can someone explain the purpose of putting the function name as a property? (I assume it is a property since it has a leading colon. This function is not wrapped in anything else)

Comment: Where did you see this? Can you provide some more context?

Comment: Was it part of an object?

Comment: This depends on context, it's either a property or a label

Comment: It's an html/javascript "game" that someone built before I started working where I am now. There's about 15 of these and they don't seem to be wrapped in anything. The game is broken so i'm fixing it.

Comment: If it's not wrapped in an object, it's a label

Comment: Are you sure they are not wrapped in anything? No Object or export?

Comment: I think @adeneo is right, it's probably a label. I removed them and it still works. I just wasn't aware of there being labels in JS.

Comment: JS does have labels, but they are rarely used. you can look at the docs posted in Quentins answer for more info on how they work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All else being equal, `funcName:`  is [a **label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and is meaningless because it isn't labelling a loop.

Comment: Came here to say this. +1

Comment: Oh, found the relevant info in the docs: `Starting with ECMAScript 2015, labeled function declarations are now standardized for non-strict code in the web compatibility annex of the specification. In strict mode code, however, this will throw a SyntaxError.`. So it's not valid strict syntax.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#Labeled_function_declarations

Answer (score 0):

For future edification.

Labels can affect the functioning of your code and can be useful. Take a nested loop for example:

```
primaryLoop:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   secondaryLoop:
   for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      if (i === 1 && x === 1) {
         break primaryLoop;
      }
   }
}
```

We can break out of the primaryLoop by referring to it using the label.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes an anonymous function. before it had the name that you could reference  inside itself, after you deleted it the function still exists, just not a named way to reference it.